# Why is my enemy script not following the Player?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Why is my enemy script not following the Player ?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class suivre : MonoBehaviour {

    GameObject perso;
    float persoposx;
    float persoposy;
    float persoposz;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        perso = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Player");
        InvokeRepeating ("follower", 1, 1);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        persoposx = perso.transform.position.x;
        persoposy = perso.transform.position.y;
        persoposz = perso.transform.position.z;

    }

    void follower() {

        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(new Vector3(persoposx, persoposy, persoposz));
    }
}
```

This script is a component on the enemy. The enemy doesn't follow the player, but still goes towards a direction - why?

Comment: It doesn't look like you're using the positional data of the player at all. You're always just applying force along the x-axis with `new Vector3(1, 0, 0)`, so it makes sense that the enemy would move but not in the direction of the player.

Comment: Bonjour JohnD, you have huge problems.  It is absolutely impossible to call InvokeRepeating inside Update. You really need to start over with the many excellent Unity tutorials to begin your hobbyist programming journey.

Comment: I edited my code, but nothing happens

Answer (score 1):

You are missing one concept of direction vector.

Your code should look like that:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class suivre : MonoBehaviour 
{    
    public float speed = 3f;

    GameObject perso;

    void Start () 
    {
        perso = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Player");
        InvokeRepeating ("follower", 1, 1);
    }

    void follower() 
    {    
        Vector3 directionToPlayer = perso.transform.position - this.transform.position;
        directionToPlayer.Normalize (); 

        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(directionToPlayer * speed);
    }
}
```

Get rid of Update method. You don't need it here.

Then create direction vector from enemy to player, normalize it, and then pass this vector to `AddForce` and multiply it by speed you want.